# Reword existing question or create new question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I'm not quite sure what the SE etiquette is for this.

The OP for the following question: [Understanding MIDI Files](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/34402/understanding-midi-files) provided some additional information in a recent edit, which allowed me to state in my answer that he is not asking the question he wants to ask. But *after* answering his question (and then searching for the tool he mentions using), it became apparent to me that his question should really be about understanding ABC notation instead of MIDI format.

Should I recommend he edit his question (or edit it myself) so that it's asking about ABC notation -- which would totally invalidate all the existing answers, which all have good information but answer the wrong question -- or should I recommend that he just ask a new question specifically about ABC notation?

Comment: Related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/399/edit-the-question-changes-the-idea-of-the-question

Comment: Thanks! Based on that, I've recommended he ask a new question.